# Can I convert a native wireless adapter into a dongle?

Tags: wireless-networking, dongle

I hold an old netbook and I wonder if it is possible to keep the internal wireless adapter from it (Atheros AR5BXB63) for creating an external USB wireless adapter and use it as a dongle for another PC. My purpose is adding an extra wireless adapter to the second PC, without substituting the internal one.

Is there any method to transform an internal wireless adapter to an external one?

Comment: @acejavelin This thing only works with cards that only use the USB connection on a Mini PCIe slot. Most WiFi cards use the PCIe connection only (or both if Bluetooth is also present).

Comment: @DanielB You are correct, I put in an incorrect link. I will delete the comment to prevent confusion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's ***possible***.  But why would you buy an adapter, when you can get high quality USB wireless dongles on Ebay for less than $10???  That card you have is huge, and over time it will be more of a hassle to keep that thing out-of-the-way than to just replace it -- especially if the adapter you purchased doesn't fully enclose the card.

Keep it simple!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113660/135565 official line on URL shorteners. I figure the OP can search on ebay or his favoured online vendor, and your answer's great on its own, so I've taken the liberty of simply removing it

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes.  Ive never seen them used, but there are mini-PCIe to USB [adapters](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mini%20pci%20to%20usb).