# Can I use my laptop WiFi adapter in my desktop?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, network-adapter, desktop-computer

OK so I got a new desktop but it doesn't have a built in adapter or anything and I can't connect through Ethernet cable so I have a old gateway laptop and I was wondering if I could take the adapter from that?(here's the link to the specs of my laptop) https://panam.gateway.com/s/Mobile/2008/Avalon/1015078R/1015078Rsp4.shtml

Edit:okay so I can't take it out of the laptop but my computer says it is a 3.00 GHz computer so what type of dongle should I get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I convert a native wireless adapter into a dongle?](http://superuser.com/questions/1077821/can-i-convert-a-native-wireless-adapter-into-a-dongle)

Comment: Probably not, but if the old machine is still running, you could bridge its wifi to its ethernet, and run a cable between the two machines.

To reduce powerusage and noise, you could remove the harddisk, and boot from either a live linux cd or install a small linux on a sd/usb/ssd.

Comment: @Ramhound So *that's* how you determined the adapter is soldered on? Wow. Like I said, do your research. Here's my research: http://www.joewein.net/blog/2011/05/29/gateway-m-6750-with-intel-ultimate-n-6300/. This guy's replacing the stock MC85 adapter with an Intel one, on a Gateway M-6750.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can take the wireless card out of the laptop. It's removable. These things are NOT soldered on.

Yes, you can use the card in a PC. But, you'll need a Mini PCI Express to PCI Express adapter, something like this:

http://www.hwtools.net/Adapter/MP1.html

It might not be worth the effort (or cost), but it is do-able.

By the way, the wireless adapter in your laptop is going to be the Marvell MC85 (TOPDOG)

[image: Marvell MC85]

Comment: Ok so if it is do-abel but a dongle would be cheaper what type of dongle should I get for my desktop it runs on at 3.00 GHz

Comment: The GHz makes no difference. OK fine, how about I tell you what I would get for myself, and then you can decide what to do for yourself. If my PC had USB 3.0 ports, I'd get this http://www.tp-link.com.au/products/details/cat-11_Archer-T4U.html If my PC only had USB 2.0 ports, I'd get this http://www.tp-link.com.au/products/details/cat-11_Archer-T2UH.html